# Session storage update items count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple counter using session storage, the objective is to show the item increase when you click on the respective add item.
I'm having problems to check if the item is in the array and if it is not add it to array.

my problem is in function itemsUpdate()

Sorry i'm can't express the problem very well,
try the demo and you will understand

here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t77hqka6/2/

```
`function itemsUpdate(items, item) {
   for (var i in items) {
     if (items[i].id === item.id) {
         console.log(items);
        items[i].value++;
         console.log(items);
         break;
     }
       else{
        items.push(item);
       }
   }
    if(items.length === 0)
         items.push(item);
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the else block in `itemsUpdate` being inside the loop that checks if an item is already in the cache or not.

Because you are looping through the entire cache, the else block will always be triggered for every item in the cache except the one just updated.

e.g

- You call it with ID=1. First time you call it, cache is empty.
- So you execute a push into the cache.
- Cache is now [ 1 ]
- Now you call with ID=2
- You loop TWICE and on the first iteration you are checking Cache[0]===2. It's not (it's 1!), so then your code *inserts* 2 again.

And so on.The solution is to return as soon as you find a match (and update it), and only execute to add to the cache if nothing was found.

See updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t77hqka6/6/)

The reworked `itemsUpdate` function is now:

```
function itemsUpdate(items, item) {
   for (var i in items) {
     if (items[i].id === item.id) {
          items[i].value++;
         console.log("Updating " + item.id + " in cart...");
         return;
     }       
   }
    //item isn't in cart, so add it
        console.log("Adding " + item.id + " to cart for first time...");
        items.push(item);
}
```

Comment: Yeahh i already remove the else my problem i think was using the break instead of return. Thank you very mutch for the help

Comment: Yep. But I recommend removing the `else` as well, it makes the code much clearer. don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Yes i've remove the else, now i've got another problem, im using the add item on part of the html that appear with the load() method and the item count is on the main page. When i click on add item nothing happens.

Comment: I understand that my script do not run again after the load and because of that don't now that new elements are in the page. how can i pass this situation?

Comment: oops, I had left a function to clear the session storage on that fiddle during debugging. Remove this line `$(document).ready(function(){sessionStorage.clear();}); ` and it should be good. Sorry :)

Comment: yes don't worry i saw that and removed i solved the other question i need to call my function after the load(). thank's one more ime